# how to define different activity's attribute for phone and tablet in AndroidManefist.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a activity, it has attribute in `AndroidManefest.xml`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but this attribute will introuce some performance in tablet, so I want change it to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I think if we can define a variable in res/values, which is different for phone and tablet. then apply this value AndroidManefist as below:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="someVlaueDefineInResources"
```